Vector space of homogeneous harmonic polynomials
We know that the vector space of homogeneous harmonic polynomials of degree $l$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is of dimension $\dim(\mathscr{H}^{l}_3)=2l+1$. My professor gave an example of a basis in this space:
$$xy \ \ , \ \ xz \ \ , \ \ yz \ \ ,\ \ x^2-y^2 \ \ , \ \ x^2 -z^2$$
My question is, how would you get a function like $x^2$ from this basis?

$x^2$ while a homogeneous function of order "$l=2$" : $(kx)^2=k^2x^2$, is not harmonic so it shouldn't be in that vector space:
$$\Delta(x^2)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}(x^2)=2\neq0$$
So it is logical that it can't be accessed through the given basis.
